# Printing a smiley using C in Netbeans

Tags: c, netbeans, cygwin

I have just now installed the **Netbeans 8** IDE along with the required **Cygwin** elements for C and C++ programming. To mark a good beginning, I coded to print a **smiley** using **C**. The following is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf("%c",1);
    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

To my shock the output printed is just a space. Can't I print smileys  using C in netbeans? Please help me make a happy beginning. . .

Comment: charsets: just because you put in a smiley char into your code doesn't mean it'll be a smiley in whatever environment you're outputting it into. e.g. a utf-8 smiley is not going to be the same codes in iso8859.

Comment: Where is the smiley in the code?

Comment: If your console supports UTF8 *and* your console font supports Unicode, you can try [the Unicode WHITE SMILING FACE](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm): ☺ (UTF-8 sequence: `0xE2 0x98 0xBA`).

Answer (score 2):

For those who may not know what the question was asking, here is old PC character set:

[image]

In the new `utf-8` world, things have changed.  In utf-8, there is a smiley, but it's just not as engaging as the old one:

`U+2639` `e2 98 b9` WHITE FROWNING FACE:

## ☹

`U+263A` `e2 98 ba` WHITE SMILING FACE:

## ☺

`U+263B` `e2 98 bb` BLACK SMILING FACE:

## ☻

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
   {
   char *smiley = "\xE2\x98\xBA";   // "☺"
   printf("[%s]\n", smiley);

   return(0);
   }
```

Comment: Your answer made me explore about utf-8. That was very new to me. Thank you for your answer. But still I don't get a smiley output. Instead I get the following bold figures as my output. **[â˜º]** . I have checked the locale settings of my cygwin. It seems like my cygwin supports utf-8. Then why can't I get the desired output. Help me more please.